# Split Microsoft SQL Row

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access

Assume I have data like so:

```
+------+------+------+------+
| Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | Col4 |
+------+------+------+------+
| a    | b    | x    | y    |
+------+------+------+------+
```

I wish to split it after a certain column to achieve something like this:

```
+------+------+
| Col1 | Col2 |
+------+------+
| a    | b    |
| x    | y    |
+------+------+
```

What would be the easiest way to achieve this? I am currently forced to do this in an old MS Access database with a connection to the SQL server. Thoughts?

Comment: you can use `union all`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `union all`:

```
select col1, col2
from t
union all
select col3, col4
from t;
```

Both databases support `union all`.  Both will take the column names from the first subquery.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
select col1 as Col1 , col2 as Col2
from t
union all
select col3 as Col1, col4 as Col2
from t;
```